# Vagrant can't set permissions for NFS share

Tags: vagrant, puppet, puphpet

I've used PuPHPet to create a manifest for a virtual machine for a project I'm currently working on.

Everything is fine up until right at the end (after "Notice: Finished catalog run in xxx.xx seconds"). It then says:

```
Stderr from the command:

stdin: is not a tty
Warning: Could not retrieve fact fqdn
Error: Failed to set owner to '0': Operation not permitted - /var/www
Error: /Stage[main]//File[/var/www]/owner: change from vagrant to root failed: Failed to set owner to '0': Operation not permitted - /var/www
Error: Failed to set group to '33': Operation not permitted - /var/www
Error: /Stage[main]//File[/var/www]/group: change from vagrant to www-data failed: Failed to set group to '33': Operation not permitted - /var/www
Warning: /Stage[main]//Apache::Vhost[ARbCsyrS6ueR]/File[/var/www/12_PHP_david_wright_images/src/web]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /Stage[main]/Apache/Apache::Vhost[default]/File[15-default.conf]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /Stage[main]//Apache::Vhost[ARbCsyrS6ueR]/File[25-ARbCsyrS6ueR.conf]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /Stage[main]//Apache::Vhost[ARbCsyrS6ueR]/File[25-ARbCsyrS6ueR.conf symlink]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /Stage[main]/Apache/Apache::Vhost[default]/File[15-default.conf symlink]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /Stage[main]/Apache::Service/Service[httpd]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
```

I have tried using regular shared folders instead but that introduced other problems, and on top of the the speed of shared folders is said to be nowhere near as good as NFS.

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 as the host operating system and the guest is Ubuntu 12.04. The configuration is fairly standard, if necessary I can edit this to include any of the files that PuPHPet has created.

What can be done to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you please show your Vagrantfile as well.

Comment: I've chosen to create my own Vagrant and Puppet setup, took a bit of learning but I think it's paid off. It actually works now at least. I also don't have that configuration file anymore, however it was just one straight from PuPHPet without being edited.

Comment: I use PuPHPet myself and had also few minor issues which had to be corrected by manually editing files. PuPHPet is currently under active development so that's expected behaviour I suppose. But overall it's really great tool.

Comment: I'll agree, it's a great tool, but I am very glad that I chose to learn how to use Vagrant and Puppet myself because now I can make a much more complex automated environment and know how to change it all down to a T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `/var/www` is indeed an NFS mount, it must be exported with the `norootsquash` option (if you dare), otherwise Puppet (typically running as root) will not be able to change its permissions.

Note that it is safer to use `rootsquash` and manage the NFS permissions server side.

Answer (score -1):

Using PuPHPet I had the same problem. The solution was for me to change the line 152 in puphpet/vagrant/Vagrant-local that it looks like this

```
        machine_id.bindfs.bind_folder "/mnt/vagrant-#{i}", "#{folder['target']}",
          after: :synced_folders,
```

So changing the "after" value to "synced_folders" did the trick for me.
Don't forget to compleatly rebuild your vagrant machine with "vagrant destroy" and "vagrant up"